# Pass by Reference with Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, reference

Why this program only works when I initialize a and b. 
I want to pass it without initializing a and b, for example:

numChange(10,15);

Is this possible ?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void numChange(int *x,int *y)
{
     *x = 99;
     *y = 77;
}

int main()
{
    numChange(10,15);
    //int a=10;
    //int b=15;
    //numChange(&a,&b);
    cout<<a<<" , "<<b<<endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you have defined your function to receive pointers, but when you call that function you are trying to pass an int.

The compiler is expecting memory addresses and you are trying to pass constants.

It does not make sense, you are trying to do something like 10 = 99; 15 = 77;?

```
numChange(10,15);
    //int a=10;
    //int b=15;
```

It seems that you are hopping that a = 10 = 99 and b = 15 = 77;

If this was possible, it means that I could never (after the call of numChange(10,15);) make a variable to actually have the value 10 because 10 is "pointing" to 99 (is not).

Answer (score 2):

Recall: a pointer is an integer containing a location in memory.

This:

```
int a, b;
...
a = b;
```

copies the integer stored at the memory location reserved for 'b' to
the memory location reserved for 'a'.

This:

```
int *a, b;
...
a = &b;
```

stores the **location** of 'b' in 'a'.  Following it with this:

```
*a = 42;
```

will store 42 in the memory location stored in 'a', which is the
variable 'b'.

Now, let's look at your code.  This:

```
void numChange(int *x,int *y)
```

tells the compiler that 'numChange' will be called with two
pointers--that is, memory addresses.  This part:

```
 *x = 99;
 *y = 77;
```

then stores two integers at the **locations** given in 'x' and 'y'.

When you call:

```
numChange(10,15);
```

the arguments are integers instead of memory location.  However under
the hood, memory locations are also integers so the compiler converts
the arguments to pointers.  Effectively, it's doing this:

```
numChange((int *)10, (int*)15);
```

(It should issue a warning when this happens, since it's almost never
a good idea, but it **will** do it.)

Basically, your call to 'numChange' tells it that there are integer
variables at memory addresses 10 and 15, and 'numChange' carries on
and stores integers at those memory locations.  Since there **aren't**
variables (that we know of) at those locations, this code actually
overwrites some other data somewhere.

Meanwhile, this code:

```
int a=10;
int b=15;
numChange(&a,&b);
```

creates two integer variables and then passes **their addresses in
memory** to 'numChange'.  BTW, you don't actually need to initialize
them.  This works too:

```
int a, b;
numChange(&a,&b);
```

What's important is that the variables are created (and the compiler
sets aside RAM for them) and that their locations are then passed to
'numChange'.

(One aside: I'm treating variables as always being stored in RAM.
It's safe to think of them this way but modern compilers will try to
store them in CPU registers as much as possible for performance
reasons, copying them back into RAM when needed.)